# using joins combine two or more tables into one Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, operators

I have two types of databases like,

**Db1:**

**Degrees**:

- ID
- Name
- Type

**Qualifications:**

- Id
- CandidateId
- DegreeId
- specialization

**DB2:**

**UG_LIST :**

- Name
- ID

**PGLIST :**

- Name
- ID

**DoctorateList:**

- Name
- ID

Here **Degrees** table is single one. All degrees like Ug, Pg, doctorate are stored single table called **Degrees**.But In database -2, every item created as separate tables. So I have to take these three table values store into **Qualifications** table.

I used joins for this. But I can't create the select query for this.

```
SELECT top(50) 'INSERT INTO CandidateQualifications(candidateId,DegreeId,specialization) VALUES('+

     Cast(c.CandidateID as varchar(50))+',''' +
    Isnull(Cast(u.Id as varchar(50)),'NULL') Or cast(p.Id as varchar(50)) or cast(d.Id as varchar(50))+','+
    IsNull(''''+c.ugspecification+'''', 'NULL')+')'
  FROM  candidatedetails as c 
  right join UG_List As u ON c.qualification=u.UGName
  right join PG_List As p ON c.qualification=u.pgname
  right join Docorate_List As d ON c.qualification=u.docorate
```

Please tell how to do this? I use Or operator but it is not accepting.

Any idea?

Comment: Hey, Can you please clarify the question little bit ? Like the title Should I join two or more tables to form a field (is this field? ). And What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I edit my question. No. its not a field. it s a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
Isnull(Cast(u.Id as varchar(50)),'NULL') Or cast(p.Id as varchar(50)) or cast(d.Id as varchar(50))
```

With:

```
Cast(Coalesce(u.Id,p.Id,d.Id)as varchar(50))
```

I'd expect the joins to be `left`

```
SELECT top(50) 'INSERT INTO CandidateQualifications(candidateId,DegreeId,specialization) VALUES('+

     Cast(c.CandidateID as varchar(50))+',''' +
     Cast(Coalesce(u.Id,p.Id,d.Id)as varchar(50))+','+
     IsNull(''''+c.ugspecification+'''', 'NULL')+')'
  FROM  candidatedetails as c 
  LEFT join UG_List As u ON c.qualification=u.UGName
  LEFT join PG_List As p ON c.qualification=p.pgname
  LEFT join Docorate_List As d ON c.qualification=d.docorate
```

Comment: @Duk have a look on the joins and edit my post if necessary, I'm not shure about the conditions ...